# Continuous motion in an image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image slider that uses sliding dividers. I'm trying to manipulate it so that when i click a button (previous/next) the switch will be continuous, as if the dividers switching are one. In the current slide, when clicking on a button, the other divider comes to replace the current divider from a far position. Any idea on how to make a single movement? While keeping the same motion as in the code (left to right/right to left).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
    <button id="prev" disabled>&lt;&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button id="next">&gt;&gt;&gt;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="mask">
    <div id="item1" class="item">
      <a name="item1"></a>
      <div class="content">
        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">
      <div class="content">
        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
#prev {
  left: 40px;
}
#next {
  right: 40px;
}
#mask {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}    
.item {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}       
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function shift(direction) {
    var 
      $mask = $('#mask'),  
      items = $('.item').size(),
      currentItem = $mask.data('currentItem'),
      newItem;

    if (currentItem == undefined) {
      currentItem = 0;
    }

    newItem = currentItem + direction;
    $mask.data('currentItem', newItem).animate({marginLeft: -1200 * newItem});

    if (newItem == 0) {
      $("#prev").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#prev").prop('disabled', false);
    }    
    if (newItem == items - 1) {
      $("#next").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#next").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }

  $('#prev').click(function() {
    return shift(-1);
  });
  $('#next').click(function() {
    return shift(1);
  });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/24jw3xub/

Comment: @RiteshKarwa extend the result part

Answer (score 0):

**Are you wanting something like this :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<style>

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

  </style>
</head>

<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li><img  src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
    <li><img  src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
    <li><img  src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
    <li><img  src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div> 
<body>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 3000);
      });

        var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
        var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
        var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
        var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

        $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

        $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

        function moveLeft() {
            $('#slider ul').animate({
                left: + slideWidth
            }, 200, function () {
                $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
                $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
            });
        };

        function moveRight() {
            $('#slider ul').animate({
                left: - slideWidth
            }, 200, function () {
                $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
                $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
            });
        };

        $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
            moveLeft();
        });

        $('a.control_next').click(function () {
            moveRight();
        });

  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Karwa , no the movement should be the same as in my code above

Comment: @randy i am not understanding your sliding effect

Comment: @randy   do you have a visual example ??

Comment: Karwa no i don't.. the dividers move as if they are one divider. When clicking on next let's say, we see the current divider going to the left while at the same time  the next divider is coming also to the left

Comment: Karwa yes that's the movement i'm looking for, but between dividers, not images.. Can it be fixed?

Comment: use a plugin its cleaner and better